# Posting a JSON true value with Mojolicious

Tags: json, perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

I am trying to post the following JSON with [`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent)

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $ip = ...
$mojo->post( 'https://$ip:443/query' => json =>  { value=> True, Query => ... } );
```

I get an error

> Bareword "JSON::true" not allowed while "strict subs"

but if I set it to `True` it is interpreted as a string and not a JSON *true* value.

Any idea how to post a JSON *true* value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Mojo::JSON::true and Mojo::JSON::false for the corresponding JSON values. You can also use the scalar references `\1` for true and `\0` for false if you want. A Perl `undef` will get converted to a JSON null.

From the [Mojo::JSON docs](http://www.mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/JSON#DESCRIPTION):

> Literal names will be translated to and from Mojo::JSON constants or a
>   similar native Perl value.
>
> ```
> true  -> Mojo::JSON->true
> false -> Mojo::JSON->false
> null  -> undef
> ```
>
> In addition scalar references will be used to generate booleans, based
>   on if their values are true or false.
>
> ```
> \1 -> true
> \0 -> false
> ```